# What is the behavior of a ball of nothingness $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash B$ in space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vacuum, topology

Let's say we have a region of the universe described locally as $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash B$, where $B$ is a [3-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)). Say that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is equipped with the standard [Euclidean metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanMetric.html). What physics can describe the behavior of this ball of nothingness, its dynamics, its evolution? 
Before I get parallels with black holes, I want to specify this ball cannot be entered since there is no space in it.

Comment: This is insufficient to say what happens, since you do not describe the metric on this manifold. The boundary of this ball could be a regular boundary, a singularity or it could be at infinity for all we know.

Comment: I'm interested in the case of a universe like ours with 3 + 1 dimensions, in any kinds of regions, such as flat space.

Comment: The manifold $\Bbb R^3 \setminus B$ is just the cylinder $\Bbb R \times S^{n - 1}$, hence the general case isn't terribly interesting. If you just mean Minkowski space minus some ball then yes, this has some effects.

Comment: 3 + 1 dimensional Minkowski space minus a 3-ball is a case that interests me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Slereah rightly points out, you haven't quite specified enough to answer your question.  But we can make some reasonable assumptions for you — like Minkowski spacetime as the background, and regularity of the metric.  I would also argue that you have actually given us boundary conditions on the surface of the ball:

> this ball cannot be entered

That sounds like a perfectly reflecting boundary condition on all fields to me.  [It might be pointed out that you also need initial conditions on the fields compatible with the presence of this ball.  But you can take any initial conditions on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and just ignore whatever would have been inside the ball — that's totally consistent.  In fact, this also allows you to take initial conditions that normally would be unacceptable because the contain singularities, for example, that are excised by the ball.]

Probably the simplest interesting analysis we could do on such a spacetime is to assume that the spacetime is flat, but has some electromagnetic field in it (and ignore the spacetime curvature due to the EM field).  Up to the surface of the ball, this is precisely the same scenario as an idealized perfect spherical mirror in ordinary E&M.  So its behavior with respect to fields on the exterior would be identical.

Other fields can get in on the act too, including other quantum fields and the gravitational field.  Just as in the E&M case, any incident disturbance would just be reflected.

Note that this scenario is indeed quite different from a black hole (never mind the possibility of [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole)), because event horizons are dynamic: they can change in response to gravitational waves entering them, and they can radiate gravitational waves as they settle back down to a quiescent state.

Comment: EM has conformal invariance, so I would know how to calculate Green functions  and what the charge would feel near a spherical mirror, yet it is not obvious (for me) how to formulate boundary conditions for the gravitational field.

Comment: There are various ways to approach boundary conditions for the gravitational field.  The standard way is to rewrite Einstein's equations in (first-order symmetric) hyperbolic form, decompose into characteristic fields orthogonal to the boundary, and then impose the boundary condition on the incoming characteristics (in this case, equal to the outgoing characteristics).

Comment: You can also rewrite Einstein's equations exactly as a wave equation sourced by an effective stress-energy (involving the quadratic terms in the gravitational field itself).  The Green's functions for the wave equation are known, of course, so you can use them to solve iteratively — if you're willing to assume that such an approach will converge to the answer, such as when the metric perturbation is "small".  [Thorne's 1980 review](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.52.299) is the standard reference for this.

Comment: Too late to edit, but in my last comment I have an extra and potentially confusing "the" in front of "quadratic terms".  To be precise: the effective stress-energy involves terms that are quadratic in the metric perturbation and its derivatives, along with the usual stress-energy tensor.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the manifold defined by Minkowski space $\Bbb R^{3,1}$ minus some ball at every spacelike hypersurface

$$B = \{ (t,\vec x) | (\vec x - \vec x_0)^2 \leq r^2\}$$

This corresponds to Minkowski space with the regular boundary $\partial B \cong \Bbb R \times S^{n-2}$. This is not an ideal scenario for a variety of reason.

There is no predictable dynamic for such a scenario. If you allow for spacetime to be very general, there is no unique development for it, even accounting for diffeomorphism invariance. This is why the generic theorem on spacetime evolution, the Choquet-Bruhat theorem, assumes spacetime to be globally hyperbolic (no naked singularities nor closed timelike curves). If we do not make this requirement, the manifold could evolve any damn way it pleases, like developing random singularities.

Your spacetime is such a spacetime : it has a giant glaring naked singularity in it. It's otherwise Riemann flat so no initial conditions will help, since it's a totally flat vacuum spacetime. The ball $B$ could be described by anything, for instance

$$B = \{ (t,\vec x) | (\vec x - \vec x_0(t))^2 \leq r^2(t)\}$$

with a variable center and radius. It could even disappear entirely, or change shape, or split, or whatever else. Those would all be valid spacetimes with the same initial conditions and matter content, as long as the boundary is the same at $t = t_0$.

Even if we assume that the metric is known in advance, our troubles aren't over. Any geodesic coming out of this ball is a valid solution of the geodesic equation, as well as any geodesic going in. This means that you can very much have particles disappearing inside or popping out of nowhere. The same applies to the wave equation : it's a perfectly valid solution of the wave equation that radiation would arbitrarily come out of it, or go inside and disappear.

In other words, there isn't much we can say about the dynamics of such a spacetime without additional informations, such as boundary conditions on $\partial B$, or some topological version of quantum gravity with a sum over topologies as is sometimes done. Overall though such spacetimes are considered to be unphysical, as it is assumed that a spacetime that is extendible (that is, there is an imbedding of this spacetime in a larger spacetime) is not physical. As xkcd mentions :

"Once you have a naked singularity, physics starts breaking down in very big ways. Quantum mechanics and general relativity give absurd answers, and they're not even the same absurd answers. "

Comment: The space in question has no singularities, it is simply geodesically incomplete (which is a different thing.)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by regular boundary points. But for the points I bring up they have the same behaviour as naked singularities.